# Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap,x,y,width,height) creating issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-bitmap, android-camera2

I am using `Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap,x,y,width,height)` for image cropping from a specific area, it is working fine but after doing certain number of operation(after capturing 8-9 images) I am getting scaled image/small image, but it is working fine in first 8-9 try.

Any help why this issue occurring?
OR
Any alternative to `Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap,x,y,width,height)` will help?